# jQuery Mobile: How to update select on pageshow

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to programatically update the options in a jQuery Mobile select input each time the page is displayed to the user (not just when the page is first created).

My attempt to do this was to update the select when a pageshow was triggered, but this breaks when data-native-menu is set to false and there are sufficient options to cause a separate dialog to display.  So, how should this be done?

The essence of the problem is the line:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", pageID, functionToUpdateSelect);
```

Such a line just isn't compatible with a select statement that uses the custom menu interface when there are lots of options.

I have put together [a small JSFiddle that shows this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/8f7rp/1/).

I see that although [someone reported this as a bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2420) two years ago, it was closed almost immediately, so I assume there must be some way out of this hole!

Comment: you tried adding seperate code under each page?
ex:
<code>
<div role="page" class="ui-content" id="page">
<script>
  $("#page").on("pageshow",myFunc);
</script>
</div>
</code>

Comment: ManZzup, thanks for your suggestion.  No I haven't tried that, but the [jQuery on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) just sets up an event handler.  I can't see how its placement in the html would impact when the handler was called, but perhaps I don't understand your idea.  You're more than welcome to update the fiddle if you have the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a *bug*, however, it can be fixed.

jQuery Mobile converts `select` with `data-native-menu="false"` into a *popup* or a *dialog* depending on number of options and *viewport*'s height. The latter acts like a *page*, hence, page events i.e `pageshow`, pagehide`, etc... are triggered on it.

To fix it, you need to check first whether `select` menu has any selected *option*. If not, set first one with `0` index as selected. Otherwise, set selected *option* as selected and refresh selectmenu.

```
function updateSelect() {

    var options = "<option data-placeholder='true'>Select an option</option>";

    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfOptions; i++) {
        options += "<option>option " + i + "</option>";
    }

    /* retrieve index of selected option 
       if -1, set first option (placeholder)
       otherwise, it returns index of selected */

    var selected = $("#p1_select option:selected").index() == -1 ? 0 : $("#p1_select option:selected").index();

    /* refresh after adding options */

    $("#p1_select").html(options).selectmenu("refresh");

    /* set selected based on value 
       retrieved in previous step 
       and then refresh selectmenu */

    $("#p1_select option:eq(" + selected + ")").prop("selected", true);

    $("#p1_select").selectmenu("refresh");
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jVah6/)**

Comment: This is a very good solution.  It means that the select can be updated whenever desired.  For my specific case, because I was unwittingly using the "unselection" feature of rebuilding the select's options, it does mean that I'll have to unselect it (set the selection to the placeholder) when processing is done.  But well done indeed!  Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewWalker the trick is to retrieve _selected_ option prior to updating selectmenu. I'm glad it worked for you.